# Problems updating elementary OS through the AppCenter

Tags: updates, appcenter

I'm experiencing two issues while trying to update elementary OS using the AppCenter. I am wondering if there is something I can do to solve both issues.

#### Freezing

Most of the times when I click the update button in the AppCenter([appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter)), the system updates will start downloading and installing but freezing my computer after a while. Most of the times I can just turn off the machine and start again without any harm done. Only once I got the black Elementary screen with different [boot](/questions/tagged/boot) options.

When I perform the updates using `apt`, there's never a problem. So I suppose there is something wrong with the AppCenter.

#### Duplication

Sometimes there are some system updates and other app [updates](/questions/tagged/updates) available. If I update them all and the app updates are coming first, a strange thing happens. Every time an app is done updating, it is visually removed from the list of items in need of an update, but then it is replaced with a copy of the elementary OS update. So if there are five items in the list (four apps and one elementary OS update), when everything is done updating, there will be five copies of the elementary OS update with the elementary OS icon and every one with the same title.

Comment: The duplication issue is covered [here](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/483).

Comment: Ok, I thought this wasn't going on unnoticed. The freezing issue is another thing though I think.